# SSL certificate in python

Tags: python, ssl

well this problems happens with quite a few of my projects such as projects using web scraping or projects that make you of servers and this problem only happens on macos and not windows

```
ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)')]
```

this is the error above

```
# bot.py
import os

import discord




client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(Token)
```

this an example with a discord bot which creates a discord instance and a uses the pc/ laptop as a server

Comment: There isn't anything in your question which would show that this is different to the [many other similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unable+to+get+local+issuer+certificate%22+macos+site%3Astackoverflow.com). If you don't think that this is a duplicate please provide sufficient details to show how this is different.